# get X-Original-Host in request Object

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, asp.net-core, http-post

Please is there a way to get X-Original-Host and X-Original-Url in Request Object ?
I checked `Request.Headers.Values` but I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
string origin = request.Headers.GetValues("Origin").FirstOrDefault();
```

i don't know if X-Original-Host and X-Original-Url you mention is same as Origin header or not but maybe you can get those 2 value by some modiffication

```
string originHost = request.Headers.GetValues("X-Original-Host").FirstOrDefault();
string originUrl = request.Headers.GetValues("X-Original-Url").FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: thanks Fadly for your answer, unfortunately it doesn't work

Comment: @Sacamoto how do you know the request you get it's really contain those 2 header ? do u have any proof of it ?

Comment: the call of my API it's done from api management, and I need to get their host, so to know that I made a logger of object Request.Headers: ```_logger.Info(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Request.Headers));``` I checked the log and there are the variables X-Original-Host and X-Original-Url there also X-Forwarded-Host...

Comment: Have you try debug mode and see why you can't get those values ?